# VBA: Open files, calculate, paste values, repeat

Tags: excel, loops, vba

I'm trying to write a macro that will Open files one by one in a provided directory, calculate all formulas, paste values over specific formulas, save, and exit, repeat process with next file.  Here's what i have below:

```
Sub LoopPaloSnapshot()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim MyPath As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim MyFolder As Folder
Dim SubFolder As Folder
Dim MyFile2 As File

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FldrPicker
    .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    MyPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")


'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:

MyPath = MyPath

Set MyFolder = FSO.GetFolder(MyPath)

For Each SubFolder In MyFolder.SubFolders

For Each MyFile2 In SubFolder.Files


If FSO.GetExtensionName(MyFile2.Path) = "xlsx" Then

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyFile2, UpdateLinks:=0)

    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Staffing Model")

       Application.Run ("PALO.CALCSHEET")
       Application.Calculate
       Application.Run ("PALO.CALCSHEET")
       Application.Calculate

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        ws.Range("B1").Select
         Selection.Copy
         Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, 
SkipBlanks _
         :=False, Transpose:=False
        ws.Range("F10:Q10").Value = ws.Range("F10:Q10").Value
         Selection.Copy
         Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, 
SkipBlanks _
         :=False, Transpose:=False
        ws.Range("F20:Q22").Value = ws.Range("F20:Q22").Value
         Selection.Copy
         Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, 
SkipBlanks _
         :=False, Transpose:=False
        ws.Range("F42:Q43").Value = ws.Range("F42:Q43").Value
         Selection.Copy
         Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, 
SkipBlanks _
         :=False, Transpose:=False
        ws.Range("F56:Q56").Value = ws.Range("F56:Q56").Value
         Selection.Copy
         Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, 
SkipBlanks _
         :=False, Transpose:=False
        ws.Range("F61:Q61").Value = ws.Range("F61:Q61").Value
         Selection.Copy
         Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, 
SkipBlanks _
         :=False, Transpose:=False
        ws.Range("F66:Q66").Value = ws.Range("F66:Q66").Value
         Selection.Copy
         Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, 
SkipBlanks _
         :=False, Transpose:=False

'Break Links
    If Not IsEmpty(wb.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)) Then
    For Each link In wb.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
    wb.BreakLink link, xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
    Next link
    End If

Dim xWs As Worksheet
For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If xWs.Name <> "Staffing Model" Then
        xWs.Delete
    End If
Next

    'Save and Close Workbook
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

'Loop

End If

Next
Next

MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

After running this, i open the newly saved files and there are #Value errors in place of the formulas im attempting to calculate and paste values over.  I've tried walking through the macro line by line and it seems to be working properly for the most part, but for some reason the formulas are not calculating.  if i open the file manually prior to running the macro, everything calculates perfectly so im wondering if something is causing these formulas to not calculate while the macro is running.  any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:  the formulas im copying and pasting values over are HLOOKUP's pulling from other tabs within the workbook, and PALO formulas pulling data directly from a JEDOX server.  i've manually ran through the process im trying to automate without errors.

Comment: Could you please add more details on what you're copying and pasting?  That's likely where the error lies.

Comment: @Graham awesome name!  i added an edit.  I hope that helps.

Comment: Glad to help, take care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of copying and pasting complex formulas, I'd suggest writing the formulas directly into the cells using this method:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Formula = "=$A$4+$A$10"
```

Pasted formulas can sometimes carry references to the original worksheet which causes chaos, whereas an explicitly set formula will not do that.

If you're really trying to take it offline then you could also use this method to set values as well.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "100"
```

Comment: i dont follow.  the formulas are already in the cells im selecting.  the purpose of this macro is to prepare the file to send out to the field where they dont have access to the data servers.

Comment: i actually think i fixed it.  i recorded a small macro to be lazy and got careless while copy and pasting.... thanks anyway for your reponse.  it inadvertently helped me realize this.

Comment: I had to do this with Essbase and Excel, had the exact same problem until I moved to the explicit method.